# Help with algebra involving residues

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \dfrac {\cos(mx)}{1+x^4}dx$$

I know I have to change the inegral to $-\infty$ as the lower limit. I understand the logic of the problem but it's the algebra in finding the residues that kills me. I know I'm only interested in the singularities in the upper half plane which are $z=e^i{^{\pi/4}}$ and $z=e^i{^{3\pi/4}}$. Can anyone help me in finding the residues for this problem? I'm only interested in that I know how to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to consider, for $m>0$

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i m z}}{1+z^4}$$

which goes to zero along the outer arc of the semicircle.  In this case, you must consider the residues in this semicircle, as you say, at $e^{i \pi/ 4}$ and $e^{i 3 \pi/4}$.  To keep the algebra simple, because the poles are simple, you may use the formula

$$\text{Res}_{z=z_0} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$$

That way, the sum of the residues at these poles is

$$\frac{e^{i m (\cos{(\pi/4)} + i \sin{(\pi/4)})}}{4 e^{i 3 \pi/4}} + \frac{e^{i m (\cos{(3\pi/4)} + i \sin{(3\pi/4)})}}{4 e^{i 9 \pi/4}}$$

which you can manipulate with a little elbow grease as follows:

$$\frac{e^{-i 3 \pi/4}}{4} e^{i m/\sqrt{2}} e^{-m /\sqrt{2}} + \frac{e^{-i \pi/4}}{4} e^{-i m/\sqrt{2}} e^{-m /\sqrt{2}}$$

which may be simplified into

$$\begin{align}-i \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}} e^{-m /\sqrt{2}}[ (1-i)  e^{i m/\sqrt{2}}  + (1+i)  e^{-i m/\sqrt{2}}] &= -i \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} e^{-m /\sqrt{2}} \Re{[(1-i)  e^{i m/\sqrt{2}}]}\\ &=-i \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} e^{-m /\sqrt{2}} \left[\cos{\left(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}\right)} + \sin{\left(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right]\end{align}$$

To get the integral, multiply the above by $i 2 \pi$ and divide by 2.

For $m < 0$, use the contour in the lower half-plane and multiply the sum of the residues by $-i 2 \pi$.  Then you get the result with the $|m|$.

Comment: It's the "little elbow grease" that the OP explicitly asks for help with. The OP states that s/he doesn't need help evaluating the integral, just finding the residues.

Comment: @FlybyNight: If you read the post closely, you would see that I only gave that short shrift so that I could give the OP an even easier way to compute the residues, or residue and hence, the integral.

Comment: Perhaps some of your post is missing from my screen. I don't see anything to help anyone get to a simple expression for the residue. There's lots of talk about contour selection, and little else.

Comment: wow that's amazing I did not know you could do that. Great method and you are missing a sin m/sqrt2 i believe (on the answer)

Comment: @Zuniga: Not sure what you mean about the sine term; does your result work for $m=0$?

Comment: @FlybyNight: a single term involving a few cosines and sines of $\pi/4$ is pretty simple in my book.  The OP seems OK with it, too, but we'll see.

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}} e^{-m/\sqrt{2}} \(cos{\left( \frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+sin(\frac m\{\sqrt2}))$$

Comment: not sure why it's not displaying^^^ I'm doing the code correctly. But Yes absolute value of m.

Comment: @FlybyNight yes he actually did help with the algebra as my problem was the form in which I was expressing it in. I was using z=e^ipi/4 and all I had to do was change this into trig form to ease up my calculations. Thanks Ron

Comment: @Zuniga: there is a MAJOR error in my calculation, which is why I am not agreeing.  You cannot use the contour I showed b/c of the exponential in the numerator.  I will make amends and do the other calculation.  My sincerest apologies.

Comment: yes I got a different calculation. But the residues are correct. Which is the only thing I needed in the first place. I got the answer buddy. Do you agree with adding a sin m/sqrt2 now?

Comment: @Zuniga: Got it.  I really apologize for that.  The method works if there is no exponential in the numerator, I should have known that but got a little carried away. And, yes, the case $m<0$ needs the contour in the lower half-plane - do you understand why?  Anyway, you are right to want to keep the algebra of the residues simple - there are tools for that, as I hoped to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes definitely understand why. The residues algebra was tough for me because I was using a different form for z. We can express it in so many ways but you cleared that up for me rewriting it into trig form. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}} e^{-m/\sqrt{2}} (cos{\left( \frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+sin(\frac m{\sqrt2}))$$

Comment: @RonGordon this is what I got. With absolute value of m

Comment: This would have been better as an update to the question as opposed to an answer, but maybe it is the answer and it is okay to answer your own questions. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti you're right the only reason I put it in the answers box is because the mathjax would not display in the comments area for some reason.